# How to understand the execution of this Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

While I was studying the `foldr` function in Haskell I came across this program and I am not able to figure out how it is executing.

```
mylength :: [Int] -> Int
mylength l = foldr f 0 l
  where 
    f x y = y + 1
```

Comment: I voted to close because, in effect, your question is "I don't understand X.  Educate me.".  In order to educate someone it is necessary to have an idea what they already know and, in this situation, what specifically is confusing.

Comment: In this situation I would bet you don't understand the `foldr` function.  So why not look at the source code to `foldr` and get an understanding of that?  Once you have that (or fail to have that) you should be able to make a more specific question.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson the source code for `foldr` looks like this:

`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`
`foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. f) t) z`

How would a newbie even know where to start with that?

Comment: @LIbby Not the generic code, the instance for lists.  `foldr k z = go where go []     = z ;  go (y:ys) = y \`k\` go ys`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson If a newbie doesn't understand `foldr`, they aren't likely to know to look for the `Foldable` instance for lists rather than the generic definition that comes up in Hoogle.

Comment: @Libby I'm not interested in debating how newbies go about searching the internet.  There are many ways they might do it and many of them, such as obvious google searches, lead to code from the Haskell Report or the [wiki foldr](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl').  I think we both agree the code you pointed to, found through one reasonable means, is not newbie friendly.  My main point is that it would help if the asker provided more direction and context with the question.

Answer (score 2):

This function will be executed when you call it with a list of numbers. `myLength [1,2,3]` should return `3`.

`foldr` takes three arguments. The first is a function: here it's `f`. The second is a starting value, the same type as you want the whole thing to return. The last argument is the list that you're going to fold up.

`foldr` works (kinda) like this: the function `f` is going to get called for every element of the list, the last element first. The first time, it gets called the last element of the list and `0`, returning `1`. Then it gets called with the second-to-last element of the list and `1` (the result of the previous call). So the result of `f` each time is the length of the list so far. When there's nothing left of the list, it returns that value it's accumulated so far (the length of the list).

A nice exercise is to try to write a fold yourself with a recursive definition. That may help you understand it better.

Comment: Actually, in `foldr` it is the last element of the list which is used together with `0`, and here `f` returns `1`. Then, the next-to-last with `1`, producing `2`. And so on.

Comment: ha, this is why I shouldn't try to SO in the middle of the night. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out LIbby Now I have a better understanding of foldr function , this was my first question on stackoverflow and I got 4 downvotes honestly speaking that was heartbreaking  for a newbie like me. Maybe It happened because my question was foolish

Comment: @DayanandChaudhary Your question wasn't foolish. Folds are an abstract concept and the official documentation for `foldr` isn't very newbie-friendly. However, it's true that on stackoverflow, *how* you ask is at least as important as *what* you ask. It was hard to answer this question because I wasn't sure exactly what you were confused about or what you already knew. This is a good resource on asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DayanandChaudhary Usually in SO, under the haskell tag, it is rare to see so many downvotes -- the haskell community here is usually very friendy. I was surprised as well. I guess the main issue is that your question did not show any effort and it was very generic. I mean, any tutorial on Haskell should cover `foldr`. If you did find a problem with any specific part of a tutorial, and asked about that, I guess the community here would be more open. Don't be discouraged -- next time, try to show you did attempt to solve your problem, and be more specific.

Comment: @chi: the question is very worthy of downvotes, and I have only refrained because -4 probably makes the point well. Expending little/no effort, asking an unclear question, not formatting code and using please-help-me pleading in the title is like painting a target on a question. I'd add that downvotes should not be seen as unfriendly, in the main - they are simple messages that offer feedback about quality.